# After El Capitan update, TeX doesn't compile

Tags: mac

I get this error when clicking "typeset" on TeXShop:

"/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions."

How do I fix this issue? (I apologize if the tag below is incorrect.)

Comment: ok thanks -- I tried "check for updates" and this errors, so I can't update it through teashop.

Comment: I also changed the path to /Library/TeX/texbin and this doesn't fix the error

Comment: If I download mactex 2015 (2.5 GB), will the old one be written over? -- I don't want 2 2.5 GB files.

Comment: Please refer to https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html for changes needed after updating to El Capitan.

Comment: This problem seems to be cropping up a lot.  Might be time to get a CW question and answer going....

Answer (score 3):

Go to Terminal type *which pdftex*

You will get a result of the form */something_1/something_2/.../something_n/pdftex*

Copy */something_1/something_2/.../something_n/*

Go to TeXShop>Preferences>Engine in the first box of that says *path settings* Paste.

That is all. This worked for me. This way you are changing the path setting manually.

Comment: This did not work for me. Terminal returned nothing at all when I typed which pdftex (or which pdflatex). I am struggling to find an answer anywhere on the web that works.

Comment: This also does not work. Should not be accepted as anwer